# Tcl How to print entire line if I know the line number

Tags: tcl

I have regexp certain lines and set the line number $idx

but I don't know how to print the content of the line $idx

ex. The content of whole line is about  AA_VERSION = Aa/10.10-d87_1

but I want to print only the part of (Aa/10.10-d87_1)

```
regexp {\d+} [lindex $lines $idx] version

print $version
```

This is my code but it puts only the part of (10)

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything after the `=`, then

```sh
regexp { = (.+)} [lindex $lines $idx] -> version
```

The `->` isn't special syntax, it's just a placeholder variable name that will contain *all* the matching text (including the equal), while `version` just gets the text in the first set of capturing parentheses.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your help . I can puts ( = Aa/10.10-d87_1) out! but is there any method to remove "="  ?    Thanks.

Comment: And can you tell me what (.+) means ? thanks

Comment: `(.+)` matches and captures any non-empty sequences of characters

Comment: @DonalFellows May I ask a question about how to remove "=" thanks

Comment: @SushJjs, I just did that. Did you try it?

Comment: Tcl regular expressions are fully described at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm

Comment: @glennjackman, hi, I tried to use  { = (.+)} but that take the wrong version, and I           used {=(.+)} , It take the correct number ,but "=" still exists , thanks~

Comment: See https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regexp.htm particularly the paragraph starting with "If additional arguments are specified after string then they are treated as the names of variables"